# Using stored procedures with cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use a SQL Server stored procedure with cakephp 3.x, but I get a database error.

This is my controller:

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

if($this->request->is('post')){
    $data = $this->request->getData();
    $param1 = $data['playId'];
    $param2 = $data['cardboard'];

    if(is_numeric($param1) && is_numeric($param2)){        
        $param1 = $data['playId'];
        $param2 = $data['cardboard'];

        $conn = ConnectionManager::get('ssql');

        $requested = $conn->query(
            'call searchPrem(?, ?)', 
            [$param1, $param2]
        )->fetchAll('assoc');


        //$exec = debug($requested);
    }
       echo json_encode( $requested );
}
```

I get this SQL error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.

How can I execute a stored procedure and retrieve the result data?

Comment: No code you've shown says anything about the `@P1` referenced in the error message. Where is that coming from?

Comment: The error is thrown (most likely) because the stored procedure is wrong. You have to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('ssql');
$sql = $conn->execute("yourfunction @id = $playId, @type = $type")->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Answer (score -4):

In Cake 2.x I used solution like below:

```
if ($connection = $this->getDataSource()->connection) {
        $statement = oci_parse($connection, "DECLARE x number; BEGIN :x := searchPrem(" . $var1 . ", " . $var2 . "); END;");

        oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':x', $result, 10);

        if (oci_execute($statement)) {
            // Success
        }
}
```

This example works with Oracle dialect. You should modify to Cake 3.x and Your database dialect.